# Python inheritance. Cannot read the attribute

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python, and I am trying to inherit a superclass.

The superclass looks like:

```
class LanguageModel:
    # Initialize and train the model (ie, estimate the model's underlying probability
    # distribution from the training corpus)
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        print("""Your task is to implement three kinds of n-gram language models:


    #enddef

    # Generate a sentence by drawing words according to the 
    # model's probability distribution
    # Note: think about how to set the length of the sentence 
    # in a principled way
    def generateSentence(self):
        print("Implement the generateSentence method in each subclass")
        return "mary had a little lamb ."
    #emddef
```

And here is the subclass

```
class UnigramModel(LanguageModel):
    def __init__(self, corpus):
        print("Subtask: implement the unsmoothed unigram language model")
    #endddef

    def generateSentence(self):
        # Gets the total number of words in the corpus
        wordCount = 0
        for sentence in self.corpus:
            for word in sentence:
                wordCount += 1
        print(wordCount)
```

I first tried to get the total wordcount in the corpus by doing the above, but it gives me an error that says "UnigramModel' object has no attribute 'corpus' when I try to call that function.

Comment: after `def __init__(self, corpus):` add `self.corpus = corpus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare corpus like mentioned above. Or you can use getter-setter methods for private attribute.

> def **init**(self,corpus): 
>   self.corpus = corpus
>   @property
>   def corpus(self): 
>      return self.__corpus
>   @setter
>   def corpus(self, value):
>      self.__corpus = value